# How to validate a Java application with Spring boot 2.x is using Hikari?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hikaricp

We are documenting the technology stack of our applications.  In one application, it connects to an Oracle database and uses Spring Boot 2.3.7 framework.
I need to definitively determine what connection pool technology it uses to connect to the Oracle database.  Because Hikari comes with Spring Boot 2.x and the application is auto-configured, there are no references to Hikari.
How can I determine if Hikari is being used?

Comment: what do you mean "there are no references to Hikari", afaik, this is documented to be used in Springs docs.

Comment: No references in the project that the application is using Hikari as its means to connect to the database.  Because the app is using the autoconfiguration of Hikari, there are no references of it in the application project.

Comment: you mean there is no _explicit_ dependency in your project of Hikari?

Comment: yes.  Because Hikari was added to Spring-boot 2.x.  And if you use the auto configuration, there are no references in the application project that Hikari is used. If there was a reference to spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, then you would know that Hikari is used for connection pooling

Comment: that is spelled in the documentation though, explicitly. there are a bunch of other stuff that you happen to bring into the project transitively.

Comment: yes it part of spring-boot 2.x.  But you don't have to use Hikari.   You could use Apache DBCP.  It seems the only way to determine if Hikari is used is to review the pom file and if no other technology is listed for connecting pooling, I guess, you can say that Hikari is used.

Comment: you are correct. you need to look at all dependencies in your pom, transitive included.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to autowire the Datasource somewhere and then sys out the class name of the Datasource to see what implementation is being used.

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

then in a method that will run after Spring initializes

```
System.out.println("DataSource : " + dataSource.getClass().toString());
```

Comment: I have to add code?  I would have hoped once I compiled, I could determine if Hikari was being used.

Comment: You don't have to add code, but if you can easily run it locally, this would definitely show you what is being used. You could also build the application and then go look at all the included jar files and try to find what connection pool library is being used.

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach, reduce logging level of Hikari, it's quite verbose on DEBUG level and gives you information about configuration, number of connections and their statuses:

```
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=DEBUG 

logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=DEBUG
```